# Laravel auth on multiple routes at once

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I have been asked to implement auth in a L5.4 application, which features some 30 routes and 16 controllers. 
Which is the shortest yet laravel-liest way to protect with auth all routes?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can write a custom auth filter (middleware), and either directly apply it to every route in your routes.php file, or you can assign the middleware inside the constructor of your controllers. I would think that the 2nd way is the better way to do it.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#controller-middleware

Answer (score 1):

Use route groups and add the middleware to the group. Therefore every route defined inside the route group would use the middleware.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-groups